# "History and chemistry exams" or "exams for history and chemistry"

Tags: word-usage

A group of students are going to take two exams tomorrow. When you are talking about the exams, which is the normal way of saying this?

> The students are to have **history and chemistry exams** tomorrow.
>
> The students are to have **exams for history and chemistry** tomorrow.

Comment: The former is probably most natural. If I was going to say it another way, I'd say "exams **on** history and chemistry". You are examined *on* a subject, not *for* it.

Comment: Though if you changed *for* to *in* it's perfectly idiomatic, and I would see no difference in the two syntaxes.

Comment: See [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exam+in+biology%2Cexam+for+biology%2Ca+biology+exam&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexam%20in%20biology%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20biology%20exam%3B%2Cc0), showing that you're more likely to have *an exam **in** biology* than *an exam **for** biology* (but it's *much* more likely to be expressed using the noun adjunct form ***a biology exam*** anyway).

Comment: Disagree with the top comment.  Yes, you can be examined "on" something, in certain contexts, but no one says that you have an exam "on" something.  Your top choice - "history exam" -  is most idiomatic in the U.S.  Also, "are to" is pretty formal sounding.  Normally we just say "the students have exams tomorrow."